# Exclude a Model's Password field wihtout causing Model Validation Failure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am working with EntityFramework, and MVC in .NET Core and have run across an issue that I'm not sure how to handle. I have a User model with a `Password` Field. I would like the User Model to be edited but I don't want the `Password` Field to appear on the same Edit View as the rest of the User Fields. Hiding the Password is easy enough but now the Model always fails validation when saving the edits.

I've toyed around with just hiding the password field in the view which works but leaves the password being displayed on the page source. I've also tried creating a `UserEditView` model but that creates a lot of translation code that shouldn't be necessary for what I'm trying to achieve.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is the code I've been working with.

**Model:** User.cs

```
public class User
{
    [Display(Name="User ID")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required()]
    [Display(Name="Email Address")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required()]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required()]
    public string Salt { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit Action:** UsersController.cs

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var employee = await _context.Employees.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
    if (employee == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    ViewData["LocationID"] = new SelectList(_context.Locations, "ID", "Address", employee.LocationID);
    ViewData["PositionID"] = new SelectList(_context.Jobs, "ID", "Name", employee.PositionID);

    return View(employee);
}


[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("ID,Email,Name,LocationID,PositionID")] Employee employee)
{
    if (id != employee.ID)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            _context.Update(employee);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!EmployeeExists(employee.ID))
            {
                 return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                 throw;
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    ViewData["LocationID"] = new SelectList(_context.Locations, "ID", "Address", employee.LocationID);
    ViewData["PositionID"] = new SelectList(_context.Jobs, "ID", "Name", employee.PositionID);
    return View(employee);
}
```

Comment: Change your model so it doesn't have that property. There is nothing wrong with having models designed for specific views, in fact that's kind of the point of MVC.

Comment: can you look up the password from the id that is sent in, set the employee.password = [looked up password], and then save? I wouldn't expose the password to the view, but you shouldn't have any issues doing it in the controller.

Comment: @Crowcoder That's one of the things I tried but having used Entity Framework and Scaffolded out the controllers when I tried I kept getting an error that the `UserEditViewModel` table did not exist.

Comment: Yeah, you would have to add the complexity of a service layer to abstract view models from the data layer representations. It is common practice if the software complexity warrants it - only you will know if it is worth the effort.

Comment: It's just a sample app so I can get used to .NET Core so A service layer probably isn't going to happen today.

Comment: ViewModels are the way to go. You don't need a whole service layer. In your [HttpGet] fill the viewmodel with what you need from your entities (AutoMapper can greatly help here). Then in your [HttpPost], if the model is valid reverse the process and update your entities. No need for those ugly Bind statements either. http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/mvc/understanding-viewmodel-in-aspnet-mvc

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you could do the following:

```
ModelState.Remove("Password");
```

which will prevent that field from being Validated.

However that's not a very clean fix. If you're not using that field in the current view, you should consider moving that field to another model.

Comment: Removing the key from the ModelState did not resolve the validation errors but the Customer ViewModel is definitely the best way to go so that's what I am doing for now.